# Print a specific words till matched string ( pattern 2 )above the matched string ( pattern 1 ) in a file

Tags: linux, string

```
object Host "os.google.com" {
import "windows"
address = "linux.google.com"
groups = ["linux"]
}

object Host "mango.google.com" {
import "windows"
address = "mango.google.com"
groups = ["linux"]

assign where "mango" in Hostgroups
}
```

I want to print the lines above the matched string till the specific pattern in a file

Ex:

I want to print the lines above the **assign where "mango" in Hostgroups** till this pattern **{** in the file

Desired output:

```
object Host "mango.google.com" {
import "windows"
address = "mango.google.com"
groups = ["linux"]

assign where "mango" in Hostgroups
```

Comment: fixed my answer to match your output. made it more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `awk` script

`script.awk`

```
/{/,/}/ { #define record range from { to }
    if ($0 ~ "{") rec = $0; # if record opening reset rec variable with current line
    else rec = rec "\n" $0; # else accumulate the current line in rec
    if ($0 ~ /assign where "mango" in Hostgroups/) { # if found exit pattern in current line
        print rec; # print the rec
        exit;      # terminate
    }
}
```

executions:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

output:

```
object Host "mango.google.com" {
import "windows"
address = "mango.google.com"
groups = ["linux"]

assign where "mango" in Hostgroups
```

Comment: This doesn't work

My expected Output:

**object Host "mango.google.com" {**
**import "windows"**
**address = "mango.google.com"**
**groups = ["linux"]**

**assign where "mango" in Hostgroups**

Comment: Could you provide any other idea

Comment: @mohamed afrid fixed for your request.