# How to match string and print lines within curly braces { } from config file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, icinga

I want to print the lines within **{** and **}** with **assign where "mango" in Hostgroups**

```
   object Host "os.google.com" {
    import "windows"
    address = "linux.google.com"
    groups = ["linux"]
    }

    object Host "mango.google.com" {
    import "windows"
    address = "mango.google.com"
    groups = ["linux"]

    assign where "mango" in Hostgroups
    }
```

Desired output:

```
    object Host "mango.google.com" {
    import "windows"
    address = "mango.google.com"
    groups = ["linux"]

    assign where "mango" in Hostgroups
    }
```

Comment: You'd probably be better off with something designed to parse Icinga configs, instead of trying to hack together a shell solution that will probably have problems in edge cases with escaped brackets/whitespace/etc.

Comment: duplicate of the same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715510/print-a-specific-words-till-matched-string-pattern-2-above-the-matched-string/56715763#56715763 . Edit your former question if there is a change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print a specific words till matched string ( pattern 2 )above the matched string ( pattern 1 ) in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715510/print-a-specific-words-till-matched-string-pattern-2-above-the-matched-string)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `awk` script

`script.awk`

```
/{/,/}/ { #define record range from { to }
    if ($0 ~ "{") rec = $0; # if record opening reset rec variable with current line
    else rec = rec "\n" $0; # else accumulate the current line in rec
    if ($0 ~ /assign where "mango" in Hostgroups/) { # if found exit pattern in current line
        print rec; # print the rec
        exit;      # terminate
    }
}
```

executions:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

output:

```
object Host "mango.google.com" {
import "windows"
address = "mango.google.com"
groups = ["linux"]

assign where "mango" in Hostgroups
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/{/h;//!H;/}/{g;/assign where "mango" in Hostgroups/p}' file
```

Turn off seds automatic printing using the `-n` option and gather up lines in the hold space between curly braces. Following the closing curly brace, replace it with the contents of the hold space and if there is a match for `assign where "mango" in Hostgroup` print it.

Comment: The Linux tag was removed (for an unknown reason). You should supply a non-GNU answer.

Comment: @jww as far as I am aware, this solution will work for the majority  of seds out there in the wild. However as I have only tested it using the GNU version I feel it is necessary to provide the qualified message.

Comment: Solaris results in *`sed: command garbled: /{/h;//!H;/}/{g;/assign where "mango" in Hostgroups/p}`*. OS X results in *`sed: 1: "/{/h;//!H;/}/{g;/assign ...": extra characters at the end of p command`*.

Comment: @jww I am surprised and saddened that my solution using  sed on Solaris and OS X behave as they do but I can only reiterate `might work for  you` in my defence. BTW perhaps those OS's prefer each command separately and this can be achieved using the `-e` option  and removing the `;`'s or by puting each command on a separate line in a file and using the `-f` option.

Comment: The above one is working , but its not working when there are {{}}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `}` doesn't appear in any other context in your input:

```
$ awk -v RS='}' '
    /assign where "mango" in Hostgroups/ {
        sub(/^[[:space:]]+\n/,"")
        print $0 RS
    }
' file
    object Host "mango.google.com" {
    import "windows"
    address = "mango.google.com"
    groups = ["linux"]

    assign where "mango" in Hostgroups
    }
```